# What is a .exp file and .lib file, and how can I use them in my C# project?

Tags: c#, .net, dll

I wanted to download the lame library for use in my C# project to convert audio. I found the files to use [here (libmp3lame)](http://www.rarewares.org/mp3-lame-libraries.php)

When I downloaded the archive, I found the `.dll` I was looking for but along with them, there were 2 others files:

- libmp3lame.dll
- **libmp3lame.exp**
- **libmp3lame.lib**

My question:

1. 1 What are these files used for? And how can I make use of them in my project apart from the `.dll` file
2. What benefit do these files give me that the `.dll` library cant?

**Edit:** I have a feeling that these files are not for use in C#. More for C++. But either way, what are those files? And what are they used for?

Comment: I believe those are for when you are compiling with C++. Don't think C# can even use *exp* or *lib* files (never tried though).

Comment: @TyCobb Yea, I had a feeling that it wont work with c# but still, what are those files used for?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/se8y7dcs.aspx | http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2727020/what-is-use-of-exp-and-what-is-the-difference-between-lib-and-dll

Comment: They are meant for other C/C++ projects to use the DLL.  You have no use for them in a C# project.  A C++/CLI project can however use them, the other .NET way to run native code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Both `lib` files and `exp` files are used with native code development (e.g. C++/VB6/Win32) and are not used at all in the .NET world.

`lib` files contain a collection of reusable code or data or both that can be statically linked and reused with your existing code. They are similar to `DLL` files, except the big difference being DLL files are linked dynamically and `LIB` files are linked statically, when you compile your program.

`exp` files are export files. There are kind of like metadata files that tell your compiler which functions in a DLL have been exported, and therefore can be reused in your statically linked program. .NET program do not require this because each .NET DLL has a special section called the CLR Metadata section. .NET programs can use reflection to pull this metadata information and see which methods are available.

Comment: Sometimes `.lib` contains actual code and data, sometimes it's just an import library (and it also can be both).

Comment: Is it possible to bundle the `.lib` and `.exp` inside the `.dll` file? I am developing a c# program based on a template from the web. The build process generates those extra files. If I use the '.dll' file alone (as a plugin for some program), I get error about encoding, but if I put the 3 files together on same directory, the plugin works fine. So, is it possible to merge them into the `.dll` file? Thanks.

Comment: @W.M. - The `.lib` and `.exp` files are used during development. They shouldn't be needed when you distribute your application. If you do not need them, then you can create a post build rule in Visual Studio, such as `del $(OutDir)\$(ProjectName).lib`.

Answer (score 0):

If you think about the method for consuming a native DLL in .NET (p/invoke), your p/invoke declarations have several parts:

- The function signature (return time, argument types)
- `DllImportAttribute` specifying the DLL where the function is found and its key in the export table (mangled name or ordinal)

In C and C++, the header file provides the first, and the import library, ending in `.lib`, provides the second.

Unlike p/invoke's `DllImportAttribute`, in C and C++ the calling convention is stored with the function signature in the header file.