# Is *.exp files necessary for linking dll to our solution?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, dll, export

I am developing an application for my client in VC++ using Visual studio 2010. I have dependency on third party for compiling my solution. So, I requested them to provide following files:

1).lib
2).h
3).dll

My question is do i also need to request for .exp file or above files will be sufficient.

Please help.

Comment: Read [answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2727020/what-is-use-of-exp-and-what-is-the-difference-between-lib-and-dll)